Can you permanently look at Eufy Alarm status on iIndows
I have had to install an Eufy alarm system as the Insurance company insisted on something.  I get too many notifications on my phone so I only look at them when I have time.  I have a chime, but I cant hear it from my room.  So I would like to connect it from Windows.
I can see that you can give a limited lease for max 24hrs to the Windows portal, but that is not workable.
Is there a way to use something on Windows to connect to it permanently.
